# Can we run firefox and Nightly simultaneously?

Tags: firefox

When I start nightly, new window of firefox is starts again, so I have to close firefox and start nightly, then if I open firefox Nightly's new window opens. What I am asking is can I run them both simultaneously?

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways of running to instances of Firefox simultaneously described in the [Mozilla wiki](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Debugging_Mozilla_on_Windows_FAQ#Running_two_instances_of_Mozilla_simultaneously):

You can either export `MOZ_NO_REMOTE=1` and start firefox (like `MOZ_NO_REMOTE=1 firefox` or `export MOZ_NO_REMOTE=1; firefox`) or use the `-no-remote` argument like `firefox -no-remote`.

To automatically do this on every login, you can add the `export MOZ_NO_REMOTE=1` line to your shells profile file (like ~/.bash_profile).

Comment: thanks but the exporting is not working

Comment: What's the error / unexpected behaviour you're getting?

Comment: I get no error but I cant open Nighlty and Firefox same time

Answer (score 2):

I think the main problem is that the executable 'firefox' is placed in /usr/bin/ for both. Take a look at this link: http://www.ghacks.net/2011/08/23/how-to-run-firefox-stable-beta-aurora-and-nightly-simultaneously/